# undefined method for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Getting this error, I am not sure why, any assistance on this would be appreciated.

```
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `description' for nil:NilClass):
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a]     33:         </th>
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a]     34:         <% @table_info.keys.each do |column_name|%>
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a]     35:           <% column = table[column_name] %>
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a]     36:           <th<%= raw ManageDevicesHelper.get_column_title(column)%><%= !column.rules.nil? && column.rules.required ? raw(' class="required"') : '' %>><%=column_name%></th>
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a]     37:         <% end %>
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a]     38:       </tr></thead>
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a]     39:       <tbody>
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a]   
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a] app/helpers/manage_devices_helper.rb:45:in `get_column_title'
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a] app/views/manage_devices/index.html.erb:36
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a] app/views/manage_devices/index.html.erb:34:in `each'
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a] app/views/manage_devices/index.html.erb:34
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a] app/views/manage_devices/index.html.erb:24
[52af604a-131e-46a8-9d93-eefa7cf13a5a] app/controllers/manage_devices_controller.rb:130:in `show'
```

in manage_devices_helper.rb

```
def self.get_column_title(column)
    print "column >>>>>>>>> ...  #{column}"
    title = if !column.description.nil?
              column.description
            elsif !column.comment.nil?
              column.comment
            else
              nil
            end
    title.nil? ? '' : " title=\"#{title}\""
  end
```

table[column_name] output is not nil too,

```
 primary: N not_null: N unique: N auto_inc: N  > port 
    primary: N not_null: Y unique: N auto_inc: N  > description 
    primary: N not_null: N unique: N auto_inc: N  > sub_type
```

Comment: Don't know what `table` is but `table[column_name] #=> nil` if you look at the logs you will see `column >>>>>>>>> ...  ` because of this `print "column >>>>>>>>> ...  #{column}"`

Comment: I do see in column:                         primary: N not_null: N unique: N auto_inc: N column >>>>>>>>> ...      > port 
                         primary: N not_null: Y unique: N auto_inc: N column >>>>>>>>> ...      > description 
                         primary: N not_null: N unique: N auto_inc: N column >>>>>>>>> ...      > sub_type

Comment: I have no idea what that comment is supposed to mean in this case. All I can say is your error is because `table[column_name]` returns `nil` for some iteration of `@table_info.keys.each` and then you are calling `column.description` which raises the error.

Comment: if i print table[column_name] its not nil too,     output >>>   primary: N not_null: N unique: N auto_inc: N here ..   > port 
                         primary: N not_null: Y unique: N auto_inc: N here ..   > description 
                         primary: N not_null: N unique: N auto_inc: N here ..   > sub_type

Comment: Tip: For debugging output use `Rails.logger.debug(...)` which puts it in your log, not just on the screen if you're using `rails server`.

Comment: Tip: Instead of `!x.nil?` you might want `x.present?` which, on ActiveRecord models, boils down to `x?` as in here `column.description?` could work. If you're only concerned about `nil`, not empty strings, even easier: `title = column.description || column.comment`.